# Write unit test for a method which need a file location

Tags: java, unit-testing, refactoring

I have a method which take a file location as an argument.

```
public void methodA(String fileLocation){
    
    // Do something
    
    methodB(fileLocation);

}

private void methodB(String fileLocation){

    readFile();

    // Do Something
    
}
```

I want to write a number of unit test for `methodA()`. The file location is a location to the YAML file and I need to write unit test for various type of YAML files. Since `methodA` get a file path as the argument I can't pass the YAML file as a String. Also since the `methofB` is private I can't directly write unit test for `methodB`.

1. What software engineer principal has been broken here?
2. How I can refactor this code as I can write Unit test as above.

At the beginning my plan was to update `methodB` as it take YAML string as an argument and make it public. But I am not sure is it a good practice to pass complete YAML string as a argument to a method since there are big number of calls to `methodB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to pass YAML file as a string? Just upload test files into your resources directory, and use them to test your logic. Secondly, for the method B, I would personally use PowerMock's ability to execute private method, here is a simple guide for that - https://www.baeldung.com/powermock-private-method. In general, it's a bad practice to change method's visibility just for sake of the tests, i.e. do not make methodB public if there is no necessity in it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I have a problem left. Since I have to write many number of unit test (various types of YAML files) I have to add all the YAML files into unit test directory? Isn't it an overkill?

Comment: May I know how many files are you going to store in resources directory? Why do you see it as a problem?

Comment: Sure, YAML file includes various configs. Lets say there is a config which take enum and and enum contains about 10 types. Then I have to create 10 YAML files just for these enums. And so on for other configs as well?

Comment: I think I got your point. So, it's more like a your decision how to design a test, but if it's an issue to have a lot of repetitive yamls, I would come up with a generic YAML file with a token on a paramter's place. In a test, I would be iterating through all values, and then save a yaml file in temporary directory, and then call your test. Also, I see now why you wanted to re-design a methodA to pass YAML as a string. Right now, it does make sense for me, so you can consider that approach as well, i.e pass the string to methodA, and generate various strings in your tests.